# How to convert multiple d3.csv data into number?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

right now after loading csv file I am looping each object within an array and converting one by one.

which looks like

```
fulldata.forEach(function(data){
      data.healthcare = +data.healthcare;
      data.a = +data.a;
      data.b = +data.b;
      data.c = +data.c;
    })
```

assume there are about 100 feature that you need to convert into number, is there a way that convert multiple feature into number at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D3 v5 introduced a very convenient method, called [`d3.autoType`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#autoType), which:

> For each value in the given object, the trimmed value is computed; the value is then re-assigned as follows:
>
> 1. If empty, then `null`.
> 2. If exactly "true", then `true`.
> 3. If exactly "false", then `false`.
> 4. If exactly "NaN", then `NaN`.
> 5. Otherwise, if coercible to a number, then a number.
> 6. Otherwise, if a date-only or date-time string, then a Date.
> 7. Otherwise, a string (the original untrimmed value).

It is very handy when you don't have **all** columns as a numeric value. For instance, using `d3.csvParse`, you just need:

```
const fullData = d3.csvParse("your_CSV_URL_here", d3.autoType);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const csv = `number,string,date
32,foo,2019-01-21
47,bar,2018-11-19
17,baz,2019-07-28`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, d3.autoType);

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.9.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, if in fact you have **all** columns as numeric values, just get all properties inside the `row` function:

```js
const csv = `foo,bar,baz
12,43,23
75,44,32
76,93,23`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  d3.keys(d).forEach(function(e) {
    d[e] = +d[e]
  })
  return d;
});

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hm... doesn't seem to work. const fullData = d3.csvParse("../assets/data/data.csv", d3.autoType);
  console.log(fullData); Just printing my path as string

Comment: In that case you have another problem somewhere, you can see that the snippet above works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of features.

```
fulldata.forEach(function(data) {
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    data[key] = +data.key;
  });
})
```